# Where can I find the mesonic decay constants in the particle data group listings?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, mesons, pions

I can't seem to find the mesonic decay constants in any of the relevant particle data group (PDG) listings. I'm specifically looking for the neutral Kaon decay constants.

- [Link to the PDG interactive guide](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/Viewer.action)

For example, where can I find the standard pion decay constant $f_{\pi}\approx 130\,\textrm{MeV}$ (or with a different convention, differing by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$, $f_{\pi}\approx 93\,\textrm{MeV}$)?

Comment: From the version I got at home (the 2016 version), it seems to be in the "Meson Particle Listings", p. 733.

Comment: @Slereah Could you post a picture of that page? (I think this should be ethically fine, since this is a PDG listing)

Comment: There you go : https://i.imgur.com/GckxAhm.jpg

Comment: @Slereah I found the equivalent 2019 PDG article. [Link to it](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-pseudoscalar-meson-decay-cons.pdf) To my surprise though, on page 14 they refuse to quote the experimental value of $f_K$ because of experimental uncertainties/inconsistencies! *"We do not quote an “experimental” value for the kaon decay constant because the value of $|V_{us}|$ (CKM matrix element) is less clear given the $∼2\sigma$ tension between the values of $|V_{us}|$ obtained from leptonic and semileptonic kaon decays."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @Slereah, I found the PDG article regarding the mesonic decay constant.

- [Leptonic Decays of Charged Pseudoscalar Mesons](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-pseudoscalar-meson-decay-cons.pdf)

In that document, you can find a summary of all the known mesonic decay constants. However, you may need to dig a bit, because they also explain all the nuances of deducing those values.

For example, it should be noted that, what is experimentally observable are not directly the decay constants $f_P$, but the products $|V_{q_1q_2\in P}|f_P$ and separately $|V_{q_1q_2\in P}|$, where $|V_{q_1q_2\in P}|$ is the modulus of the $(q_1,q_2)$ CKM matrix element, where $q_1$ and $q_2$ are the flavors of the valence quarks in the pseudoscalar meson $P$. Therefore, one experimentally extracts the value $f_P$ by dividing:

$$\frac{|V_{q_1q_2\in P}|f_P}{|V_{q_1q_2\in P}|}$$

Theoretical calculations, with input of some other mesonic numbers such as the pion mass or pion decay constant, can directly calculate $f_P$. It is important to mention this because the CKM matrix element $|V_{us}|$ has an inconsistent value between different experiments (see details on page 14 of the paper linked above), and therefore the authors refuse to explicitly quote the value of $f_{K+}$! (the $K^+$-meson is comprised of up and strange quarks) From page 14:

> "We do not quote an “experimental” value for the kaon decay constant
>   because the value of $|V_{us}|$ is less clear
>   given the $∼2\sigma$ tension between the values of $|V_{us}|$ obtained
>   from leptonic and semileptonic kaon decays."